# Costs of backing up S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication, amazon-glacier

I have a very large bucket. about 10 million files of 1MB, for a total of 10TB.

Continuously files are added to it (never modified). Let's say 1TB per month.

I backup this bucket to a different one on the same region using a `Replication` config.

I don't use Galcier for various availabilty and costs considerations.

I'm wondering if I should use `Standard` access or `Infrequent Access` storage. As there is a very large amount of files and I'm not sure how the `COPY` request cost will effect.

What is the difference of costs between the different options? The cost of storage is quite clear, but for copy and other operations, it's not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good rule-of-thumb is that **Infrequent Access** and **Glacier** are only cheaper if the objects are accessed **less than once per month**.

This is because those storage classes have a charge for data retrieval.

Let's say data is retrieved once per month:

- Standard = `$0.023/GB/month`
- Standard - Infrequent Access = `$0.0125/GB/month` plus `$0.01/GB` for retrieval = `$0.0225`
- Glacier = `$0.004/GB/month` plus ~ `$0.01/GB` = `$0.014` -- a good price, but slow to retrieve
- Glacier Deep Archive = `$0.00099/GB/month` + `$0.02` = `$0.021`

Therefore, **if the backup data is infrequently accessed, (less than once per month) it would be a significant saving to use a different storage class**. The Same-Region Replication configuration can automatically change Storage Class when copying the objects.

The Request charges would be insignificant compared to these cost savings.

Comment: Wouldn't the costs of the COPY requests as part of the replication be extensive?

Comment: A COPY request is `$0.005 per 1000` for Standard, `$0.01 per 1000` for Std-IA and `$0.05 per 1000` for Glacier. With 10 million files (spread over time), that cost would be $50 for Standard through to $500 for Glacier. That is trivial compared to the storage savings for Glacier. Assuming no retrievals, 10TB stored in Standard would be $230/month while Glacier would be $40/month. So, Glacier pays for itself quite handsomely after 2-3 months of backup storage. (Please note that I quite possibly have errors in my calculations, but it should be "in the ball park".)